# SMART: Reset B8 (end-to end data match) error count

Tags: hard-drive

My *Samsung HD642JJ* HDD, connected with non-faulty power data cables, shows me the "Hard drive failure imminent" warning at the boot screen. There was another, silently, truly failing HDD that I wanted to remove. The warning's cause is unique in that, because, I thought at the moment, Serial ATA disks were automatically quickly-removable in addition to being hot-pluggable, **I unplugged both disks while Windows was running** (my mistake), not knowing that the aforementioned error will have been misrecognized as disk failure. Setting disk optimization to "quick removal" did not come to mind then.

*[Samsung SMART B8 parameter(End-to-End error) fail. What does it mean? What could be the cause? What should I do?](https://superuser.com/questions/240284/samsung-smart-b8-parameterend-to-end-error-fail-what-does-it-mean-what-could)* and *[Failing end-to-end-error on new drive](https://superuser.com/questions/846573/failing-end-to-end-error-on-new-drive)* do not mention a solution that sets the error count back to zero. Here is [an *HDTune* screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cKij.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short answer:

You can't.

### Slightly longer answer:

SMART is an internal feature of a hard drive to monitor its own health and performance, giving you a quick metric to see any potential failures on the drive (As I'm sure you're aware). These values are read only, only written to by the drives firmware itself.

There is no available way for an end user to reset these. Whether they can be reset by the manufacturer themselves I'm not sure. Bear in mind that some people buying or selling hard drives will use this as a quick overview to how healthy the drive is, in a similar fashion to checking the odometer on a car.

You may have a setting in your BIOS to suppress these SMART warnings and allow your machine to boot regardless of them (assuming it currently waits for a confirmation from you to boot), but then bear in mind that if you do get any legitimate errors you won't be alerted to them.

Comment: I have backed-up my important files from the "false-positive failure" HDD when I asked this. What would you suggest that I do with it?